# Can IF statement work correctly to build spark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have following code which uses an IF statement to build dataframe conditionally.
Does this work as I expect?

```
df = sqlContext.read.option("badRecordsPath", badRecordsPath).json([data_path_1, s3_prefix + "batch_01/2/2019-04-28/15723921/15723921_15.json"])
if "scrape_date" not in df.columns:
    df = df.withColumn("scrape_date", lit(None).cast(StringType()))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```scala
val result = <SOME Dataframe I previously created>
scala> result.printSchema
root
 |-- VAR1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- VAR2: double (nullable = true)
 |-- VAR3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- VAR4: string (nullable = true)

scala> result.columns.contains("VAR3")
res13: Boolean = true

scala> result.columns.contains("VAR9")
res14: Boolean = false
```

So the "result" dataframe has columns "VAR1", "VAR2" and so on.
The next line shows that it contains "VAR3" (result of expression is "true". But it does not contains a column called "VAR9" (result of the expression is "false").

The above is scala, but you should be able to do the same in Python (sorry I did not notice you were asking about python when I replied).

In terms of execution, the if statement will execute locally on the driver node. As a rule of thumb, if something returns an RDD, DataFrame or DataSet, it will be executed in parallel on the executor(s). Since DataFrame.columns returns an Array, any processing of the list of columns will be done in the driver node (because an Array is not an RDD, DataFrame nor DataSet).

Also note that RDD, DataFrame and DataSet will be executed "lazy-lly". That is, Spark will "accumulate" the operations that generate these objects. It will only execute them when you do something that doesn't generate an RDD, DataFrame or DataSet. For example when you do a show or a count or a collect. Part of the reason for doing this is so Spark can optimise the execution of the process. Another is so it only does what is actually needed to generate the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  Actually what I really want to know is: is the IF statement executing only on spark driver ? or it will be emitted to run on executor?

Comment: df.columns is a list (i.e. not an RDD, DataFrame or DataSet). Therefore it executes locally on the driver. In my example, result.columns is a scala Array (probably an array in Python to). So yes, the check for a column name will execute in the driver node. As a general rule, operations that return an RDD, DataFrame or DataSet will execute in the cluster (executors)

Comment: thanks, this is what I want to know, pretty clear now